# a question about Example 7.6.3 in chapter II of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the example, let X be the nonsingular cubic curve 
$$y^2 z = x^3 - x z^2$$ 
in $\mathbb P_k^2$, $P_0$ is $[0,1,0]$, it is said that the invertible sheaf $\mathscr{L}(P_0)$ is not generated by global sections. Otherwise, $P_0$ would be linearly equivalent to some other point $Q$ of $X$. I want to know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall the definition of $\mathscr{L}(P_0)$: it is the sheaf of rational functions that are regular except that they might have a simple pole at $P_0$. If $\mathscr{L}(P_0)$ were generated by global sections, it would in particular have some global section $f$ which has a simple pole at $P_0$.  Now consider the principal divisor $(f)$ of this rational function $f$.  Since a principal divisor has degree $0$, but the only pole of $f$ is $P_0$, $f$ must have just a single simple zero at some other point $Q$, so $(f)=Q-P_0$.  But then $Q$ and $P_0$ are linearly equivalent.

Comment: I learn, thank you very much!